# How to expire codeigniter session when the browser window is closed

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I am using codeigniter for this task. in config file, by default value is false. but i want that if user have not checked the remember_me check box then it should be set to true. I have searched on the internet and found this. but it didn't helped. Session is still active after i close and reopen the browser( even i have unchecked the checkbox)

```
if ($this->input->post('remember_me')==null) {
                    $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = TRUE;
                 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the newest versions of CodeIgniter, the expiration of the session when you close the browser is set as follow in the config.php file (/application/config/config.php):

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
```

This is explained on the comments above the session part:

> | 'sess_expiration'
>   |
>   |   The number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
>   |   Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed.

Changing that variable based on the user check box should do the trick.

For changing it on the controller you should read this.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html

Hope it helps.